# Java get access to JComboBox from load class

Tags: java, class, jcombobox

I load some class which JComboBox. I try to add item to this combbox. Try to do like this:

```
Class<?> MakeClass = Class.forName("com.main.MyClass");
Field field = MakeClass.getField("ComboBoxVar");
 ((JComboBox)field).addItem("test");
```

but have an error: 
Multiple markers at this line
    - JComboBox cannot be resolved to a type
    - JComboBox cannot be resolved to a type

Please help, how to access to the component loaded from another class?... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the import statement for the `JComboBox`:

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but now have error: Cannot cast from Field to JComboBox

Comment: Hava a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29 . This tells you how to access a field using reflection.